# What are some of the best practices for laying out Entity Models?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

Initially we wanted to clearly separate our database into logically separated entities. However we ran into several conflicts with our domain service classes.

Now it seems that the best approach for working with complex database models is to load all tables/stored procedures/views into one entity model and then separating the functionality through the domain service classes/repository classes.

Thoughts ?

What are your architecture approaches for laying out entities ?

Also are there any performance pros/cons of having everything in one model ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe separating model into several diagrams is a good idea?
The latest build of [Entity Developer](http://devart.com/entitydeveloper) gives an opportunity to create independent diagrams containing different entities from the model.

Comment: downvoted for trying to promote your product instead of answering the question... before i can diagram my models i need to know how i want to build them.

Comment: @Robotsushi, a simple solution is to build one large model, pregenerate views for the model for startup performance, and then divide the classes into several diagrams. Of course, if your model contains several parts that will never be used simultaneously, the better way is to divide the database structure into several models and contexts.